# How can i use the rem function with a variable?

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump

i want to use the rem function with every element in a string v[j], i tried with `rem(v[j],3)` but i get the following error `MethodError: no method matching rem(::VariableRef, ::Int64)`.
Can i use rem with a string? is there any other function that does the same?

Comment: As the error message suggests, `v[j]` is a `VariableRef`, not a string

Comment: @ForceBru okey, but the question remains... sorry if it seems too easy/basic, i'm new at coding and trying to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `rem` with JuMP variables. Use a mixed-integer linear reformulation instead:

```
model = Model()
@variable(model, x)
@variable(model, y, Int)
@variable(model, rem)
@constraint(model, x == 3y + rem)
```

p.s. Since you've posted a few questions in quick succession, come join the JuMP community forum: https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13. It has more JuMP-specific questions than stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "some string"

rem.(Int32.(collect(s)), 3)
```

`collect` yields all `Char`s of a string. This will work regardless of what unicode characters are contained within the `String`

Comment: The hint is that they have a `VariableRef` in their error, so it's not a general Julia question.

Comment: I followed the part `Can i use rem with a string?` :)   Seems my guess what they need was wrong this time ;)